# COUNTIF based on adjacent cell - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need a function in Google Sheets similar to `SUMIF` which counts non numeric values (text), which separates criteria from counted range.

In column 2 below, I need to count all words with their respective activity ID (column 1).

So something like `COUNTIF($A2:$A, 1, $B2:$B)`. Unfortunately, `COUNTIF` doesn't take a third parameter.

So below, `COUNTIF` for `activity 1` would be 3 since there are three value cells with `activity 1`. For `activity 2`, it would be 2.

**NOTE**: I've tried something like `=IF($A2:$A=1, COUNTA($B2:$B),"")`, but this just counts all text values in range regardless of criteria of adjacent cell.

[image]

Comment: @player0 they're a lookup from elsewhere. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A2:B, "select A, count(A) where A is not null group by A label A 'ID'", 0)
```

[image]

if you want only pure count use:

```
=QUERY(A2:B, "count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A)''", 0)
```